# Highchart changing crosshair color depending on value of y-axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to change the colour of the crosshair depending on the value. I am doing this, but it isn't working.

```
xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            crosshair: {
            threshold: 1,
            negativeColor: 'green',
            color: 'red',
            width: 1.5,
            snap: false
            }
```

So i wanted the color of the crosshair to be green if the value of the y-axis is less than 1. But it isnt working. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options which you have tried to set doesn't exist in the API - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.crosshair.color

I think that the easiest way to achieve it is by using the `className` property and changing crosshair style dynamically in the **tooltip.formatter** callback.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/be9jqh6s/

```
  tooltip: {
    formatter(tooltip) {
      let chart = this.series.chart,
        crosshair = document.getElementsByClassName('custom-crosshair');

      if (crosshair[0]) {
        if (this.x > 4) {
          crosshair[0].style.stroke = 'green'
        } else {
          crosshair[0].style.stroke = '#cccccc'
        }
      }
      return tooltip.defaultFormatter.call(this, tooltip);
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: I think i get it but i am stuck with the actual implementation.  My graph is similar to https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/arearange-line/    In this, if i wanted that when the temperature is above 20 change the color of the crosshair to red, How would i do that ? thanks

Comment: Would you like to achieve something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qje9xbuf/ ?

Comment: yes, sort of. I tried putting the code, but it isn't working. the data in my graph is similar to my above comment as in the data is var average = [ ] and ranges = [ ] and then i call it in the series with series: [{
         name: temp, data: average}, {name: range, data:range}]

Comment: Like here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cnozgysw/? Could you reproduce the issue which you are struggling to?

Comment: this is working, the only issue is that, I'm not able to do `shared: true` in tooltips now.

Comment: Works like a charm now. I think `let chart = this.series.chart` was causing the issue. Highcharts has amazing support.

Comment: @gandalf Thank you so much. I'm glad I could help!